# Omission or inclusion of curly braces in for loop logic - what is the difference?

Tags: apex

I see differences in use of curly braces in for loops quite frequently.

One style is to be very explicit with the curly braces at the end of a for/if statement. For example:

```
for (Opportunity opp : opportunityList){
```

Another style I see is that there is an omission of this curly brace at the end of a for/if statement. For example:

```
for (Opportunity opp : opportunityList)
```

So as I understand it, the difference is that the former is explicit and the latter is implicit and usage is based on personal preferance (the latter being more concise, but the former maybe being force of habit).

Is that correct? Or is there a difference between the two in terms of performance?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the number of statements following the for/if is single you don't have to use curly braces.

But if the number of statements is more than one, then you need to use curly braces. If you don't use curly brace in this scenario, then the first line will execute only in the context of for/if, other lines will execute at all times.

**Example:**

```
if(condition){ // Not required
    statement1;
} // Not required

if(condition) { // Required
    statement1;
    statement2;
} // Required

if(condition)
statement1; // This will execute if condition satisfies
statement2; // This will execute anyway

for(iteration condition){ // Not required
    statement1;
} // Not required

for(iteration condition) { // Required
    statement1;
    statement2;
} // Required

for(iteration condition)
statement1; // This will execute for n times
statement2; // This will execute only once
```

Hope it helps to understand.

Answer (score 6):

Omitting curly braces, even where optional, is bad practice.

This is because it's easy to misread this:

```
if(condition)
  doSomething();
```

...as this:

```
if(condition){
  doSomething();
}
```

Then when someone else has to maintain your code, and assumes that they can add a statement to your conditional block like so:

```
if(condition)
  doSomething();
  deleteEverything();
```

...They find that they've just deleted everything, despite `condition` being `false`.

This is a real problem that causes bugs.  See [this account](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/02/22/applebug.html) of Apple's SSL/TLS bug for example.

Hence, good styleguides such as [Google's](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s4.1.1-braces-always-used) will tell you:

> 4.1.1 Braces are used where optional
>
> Braces are used with if, else, for, do and while statements, even when
>   the body is empty or contains only a single statement.

Comment: That'll teach them not to use _faux_ indentation for evil purposes again.

Comment: Exactly, smeghead.